# I like playing together?

Tags: grammaticality

If I am talking about what I like to do with my friend, can I say "I like doing such-and-such together" (not "together with her") or does it have to be "WE like doing ... together"?

Comment: *Together* requires a plural complement, so it must either be "We like playing together" or "[A person] likes playing together with [another person]."

Comment: With context, this construction makes perfect sense. For example, you might tell your badminton partner, "I love playing badminton together." I am not sure it's likely even to be the best phrasing to use for a particular idea.

Comment: @MikeGraham: OP doesn't provide context, so I think we have to respond in a "universal" way—which is always hard.

Comment: Please don't comment on Qs that should simply be migrated to ELL (or perhaps just closed)

Comment: Thank you all. I thought I did provide context, instead of just asking "what's correct: I or we?".

Comment: @Fattie: Maybe you should weigh in sooner so we'll know what the right thing to do is. Because, you know,  I'm kinda new here and just learning my way around.

Comment: @Fattie There is nothing "simple" about this question. Based on clarification, it would require a quite involved answer—one much more appropriate here than at ELL. (Good luck actually explaining why *I like eating together* is wrong. I'm not about to attempt a detailed answer …)

Comment: @Robusto , I appreciate the humour :)  But (i) i wasn't addressing you, it was just a general paste that has been made thousands of times (ii) it is kind of a strange thing about these sites that "nobody owns them" and when more-experienced users paste in etiquette suggestions or whatever ("don't forget to tick an answer!") it is a bit - well - weird.  (I just had a 12 yr old telling me what to do, probably correctly, on the video game site, WTF)  (iii) there's no time for every passing comment to have polite phrases (just a suggestion! you may find that! etc) typed on the front!

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica , hmm, it could be that there could be an ELU question about the issues raised by this question.  But this is a plain and simple E.L. who has a trivial E.L. question and it should be migrated to E.L.L. !

Comment: @Fattie I completely disagree that it's "trivial." Sure, you can say you believe it's one way as opposed to the other. But unless you simply want to justify it with "because," there is no explanation you can give that's trivial in any way.

Comment: (After playing games with a friend.) "I like playing together." "So do I." That seems entirely idiomatic to me. As does "we like playing together" in a different context.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica , I actually retracted my close vote, since, I still do not really agree with you *(to repeat my view: the question is a basic beginner question, asked explicitly and overtly by a beginner, who wants a beginner answer; the sophisticated issues you are discussing are only relevant to, uh, you and me, as it were)*, but you've clearly thought about it more and if it's worth you commenting on my close vote, out of general respect I've removed my close vote!!!